# PHP Hard time understand this function

Tags: php, function, user-defined-functions

I have this function written by another programmer, but he quit long ago.

I was trying to understand this function that he wrote, but I don't fully understand it.

It's getting a **token** from the **csv file**, and the quantity should depend how much I choose. But what the **force_plaform** variable does?
Also what the **$_GET** x-parameter and **$_COOKIE** x-parameter do?

```
// Get a purchaselink from a given token (if one exists) and a given csv
function getPurchaseLink($token, $csvfile, $force_platform = "", $quantity = 1)
{
$fp = fopen($csvfile, 'r', true);
$columns = fgetcsv($fp, 1024, ',');

while (($row = fgetcsv($fp, 1024, ","))) {
    $row = array_combine($columns, $row);
    if ($row['purchaseToken'] == $token) {
        $purchaseLink = $row;
        break;
    }
}

// Default to pucharse link
$url = http://www.purchase.com//?p1=zzM5X9k4dF%2BDzrTnixoaKw3Fg7wZ8h5pkjp%2BLEidTXBg40xOjcFj5PtPlQniMskLm0W3ti65mE2KafUifZe9dZAcE&ref=purchase.com&style=146&ga=UA-2689090-1&C1=C01507;1;0&C2=C0508;0;0;
if ($url) {     
  // Convert GET x-parameters to cmp, mkey1 and mkey2 if they are present
  $append = "";
  if((isset($_GET["x-source"])) && ($_GET["x-source"] != "")) {
    $append = "&cmp=source_" . $_GET["x-source"];
    $nextParameter = "x-" . $_GET["x-source"];
    $counter = 1;
    $searching = TRUE;
    while(($searching) && ($counter <= 2)) {
      if((!isset($_GET[$nextParameter])) || ($_GET[$nextParameter] == "")) {
        $searching = FALSE;
      }
      else {
        $append .= "&mkey" . $counter . "=" . str_replace("x-", "", $nextParameter) . "_" . $_GET[$nextParameter];
        $nextParameter = "x-" . $_GET[$nextParameter];
    $counter += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  // Convert COOKIE x-parameters to cmp, mkey1 and mkey2 if they are present and there are no GET x-parameters
  if(($append == "") && (isset($_COOKIE["x-source"])) && ($_COOKIE["x-source"] != "")) {
    $append = "&cmp=source_" . $_COOKIE["x-source"];
    $nextParameter = "x-" . $_COOKIE["x-source"];
    $counter = 1;
    $searching = TRUE;
    while(($searching) && ($counter <= 2)) {
      if((!isset($_COOKIE[$nextParameter])) || ($_COOKIE[$nextParameter] == "")) {
        $searching = FALSE;
      }
      else {
        $append .= "&mkey" . $counter . "=" . str_replace("x-", "", $nextParameter) . "_" . $_COOKIE[$nextParameter];
        $nextParameter = "x-" . $_COOKIE[$nextParameter];
    $counter += 1;
      }
    }
  }
  // Return upclick purchase link   
  return $url . $append;
}

if ($quantity != 1) {
    $url .= "&quantity=" . $quantity;
}

// Pass on tracking parameters from URI query and cookies
$append = "";
foreach($_GET as $parameter => $value) {
    if(strpos($parameter, "x-") === 0 || $parameter == "tracking" || $parameter == "serial" || $parameter == "affiliate") {
        $append .= "&" . $parameter . "=" . $value;
    }
}
if (empty($append)) {
    foreach($_COOKIE as $parameter => $value) {
        if(strpos($parameter, "x-") === 0) {
            $append .= "&" . $parameter . "=" . $value;
        }
    }
}

$append = str_replace("x-tracking", "tracking", $append);
$append = str_replace("x-affiliate", "affiliate", $append);
$append = str_replace("&serial=", "&x-serial=", $append);

return $url . $append;
 }
```

Comment: Most likely he left a mess:)

Comment: Mostly.... Because I can't find anything that relate to the force_platform variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is building a query string (URL) and returning it.  What the program does once it calls that URL is not up to this code, but the code on the page that gets called.  This code just generates a URL.  As to `force_plaform`, it does not appear to be being used in the function at all (just in the function header).  It is an unused variable.  As to the `$_GET` and `$_COOKIE` variables, the code is simply checking if they exist, and appending them to the query string if so.

Comment: oh thank you, That was what i'm thinking, the force_platform make me confuse about that function.... :)

Comment: Since you're new:  You're welcome, but don't forget to +1 answers that you found helpful and/ or except them as the answer to your question.  This question may be too localized, therefore, after you award points to the users that have helped you, you may request to close the question, since it probably won't help anyone else as it is very specific to your environment.

Comment: ok sure XD, how do i close it?

Comment: Right under your question tags, you should see an option to vote to close the question, for the reason of its being too localized.